# Entry Wood Door Repair on Finish

Tags: wood, doors, hole-repair

We have double entry doors and when I removed our old handle set, it took away alot of the paint that was originally on the door near the handlesets.

Needless to say, I want to try to fix this issue myself if possible.

[image]

close up

[image]

Any suggestions how I would go about doing this? I purchased a wood filler and have not decided if that would solve this issue.

Comment: Are you going to install a new handle set, or are you hoping to just fill these holes?

Comment: @shimonRura Installing a new Handleset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick solution is a mending plate, or mending rings, which cover the damaged area with something decorative. Or pick a lockset whose decorative rose is large enough to cover that area.

Answer (score 0):

if your new handle set does not cover to bare areas (look for something with a large coverplate?), you will need to sand down the adjacent area so that no height difference between the painted area and the bare wood is noticeable.  Anything less and you will see the damaged area.

You can try to fill the recessed area with plaster(joint compound) and lightly sand...wood filler will be to course.

Comment: Joint compound is much too soft for this type of repair. Many wood fillers can be smoothed adequately to be painted. A two part epoxy filler like Bondo can also be used.

Comment: Yeah, Rock Hard Water Putty or another wood filler would be better.